# Android studio Timer task crashes app on startup

Tags: android, timer, crash, timertask, chronometer

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private TextView timerTextView;
private Button pauseStartBtn;
private Button resetBtn;
private Button productiveBtn;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;


private Boolean run;
Timer timer = new Timer();
private long timeMS = 0;
private long seconds = 0;
private long minutes = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timerTextView = findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
    pauseStartBtn = findViewById(R.id.pauseStartBtn);
    resetBtn = findViewById(R.id.resetBtn);
    productiveBtn = findViewById(R.id.productiveBtn);

    startUp();


}

TimerTask taskUp = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (run){
            timeMS++;
            seconds = 0;
            minutes = timeMS / 60;
            if (timeMS < 60) {
                seconds = timeMS;
            } else seconds = timeMS - minutes * 60;

            String form = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

            timerTextView.setText(form);

        }
    }
};

public void startUp(){
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskUp,1000,1000);// change period back to 1000
}
```

}

This is the whole code anyways whenever I run the app it instantly crashes.

If it matters, the app I'm trying to create is a chronometer of sorts and when I press a button it uses the time that I got from the chronometer to run a timer, and once that timer hits 00:00 it continues as a chronometer and I convert it to a timer, and so on.

I'm still in the very early stages but what I'm trying to do is to create a basic chronometer using the TimerTask and for some reason when I run the app it insta crashes. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Log Cat

2020-04-09 18:25:46.428 5761-5870/? D/PowerKeeper.AppBgIdle: setUidState, uid = 10298 allow = false
2020-04-09 18:25:50.569 4911-4911/? W/AppStateLoggerT: type=1400 audit(0.0:66626): avc: denied { read } for name="osrelease" dev="proc" ino=6324986 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c165,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

Comment: Kindly show error log.

Comment: edit your post with the logcat please !

Comment: I edited in the logcat for not sure if this was the appropriate format tho. If it is unclear and there's a better way to post it lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

`TimerTask` callbacks are executed off the main (UI) thread, while UI calls like `setText` need to be on the UI thread.  You should wrap your call to `setText` in a call to `timerTextView.post(...)` in ordered to have it called on the UI thread.

Comment: Can you rephrase this , so that an almost absolute beginner can understand? I'm pretty new to this whole programming thing.